# How to generate six random hex colors and put them in a Ruby array?

Tags: ruby, colors, hex, rmagick

I'm making a project with RMagick that generates a random banner advertisement with respect to size and colors.

First step is this, but it does not work properly. I'm using what's called a ternary statement to make the string like "#ffffff, #f0f1cd, #123fff" etc.

```
# Generate sixteen random colors
1.upto(16) { |i|
    (defined? colors) ? colors << ", #%06x" % (rand(0xffffff)) : colors = "#%06x" % (rand(0xffffff))
}
puts colors.split(',')
```

The desired outcome is not correct. I want it split into an array like:
    ["#ffffff", "#f0f1cd", "#123fff"]

In the most elegant approach possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this which will be easier:

```
colors = 3.times.map{"%06x" % (rand * 0x1000000)}
```

NOTE: If your are using Ruby 1.9.3, you can use ranges.

```
colors = 3.times.map{"%06x" % rand(0..0xffffff)}
```

Comment: +1 with a small addition - this way #ffffff will never be produced. `rand` is in the range \[0;1\[ (see [Kernel#rand](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-rand)), that is 1 is not included.

Comment: @emboss Thanks, you are right. I've edited to include #ffffff

Comment: I would, but I didn't ask the question :)

Comment: Hehehehehe sorry, my bad :)... I've just realized that, sorry hehe